# (iphone) uiimage, view, subviews memory management

Tags: iphone, memory-management, view

I need to release uiimage/view/subviews when I want, and have a few questions regarding proper practice of releasing them.

1. [imageView removeFromSuperview] would release the imageView and imageView.image?
2. view = nil; would release its subviews/and associated uiimages recursively? if not, should I implement a recursive function to release a view's subviews?

Thank you

---

Edit.

I looked at UIView's library reference

addSubview --

> This method retains view and sets its
>   next responder to the receiver, which
>   is its new superview.

removeFromSuperview --

> If the receiver’s superview is not
>   nil, the superview releases the
>   receiver. If you plan to reuse a view,
>   be sure to retain it before calling
>   this method and release it again later
>   as appropriate.

still not sure [imageView release] releases uiImage associated with it,
and would I still need recursive releasing of subviews. ie a view's getting dealloced would automatically guarantee it's subviews release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [imageView removeFromSuperview] would
>   release the imageView and
>   imageView.image?

[removeSuperView calls release on the view](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html), but you should pay attention to the views retain count. Just because you called removeFromSuperview doesn't mean it's doing what you want.

> view = nil; would release its
>   subviews/and associated uiimages
>   recursively? if not, should I
>   implement a recursive function to
>   release a view's subviews?

No, you probably want to do (depending on how you've managed your subviews during their creation. If the superview was their only reference, they likely have a retain count of 1 and therefore calling release after calling removeFromSuperview will result in an error):

```
for (UIView* subview in view){
    [subview removeFromSuperView];
    [subview release]
}
[view release];
```

EDIT: To answer your final question, no, calling release on a view does not automatically call release on all of its subviews. You have to do it yourself, whether with release or with removeFromSuperview.

Comment: i said 'release' not dealloc, I know memory will be dealloced when its retain count goes zero.(I know i'll have to handle all other references) Thanks for clarification on recursive subview release. I'll have to implement recursive removeFromsuperview(or release) to release all decendents of a view's subview. :(

Comment: and yes, what about imageView.image = nil is required to release uiImage or [imageView release] will release the imageView.image as well?

Comment: you can assume UIImageView releases all of its data when it is dealloced. Until then, calling release on a UIImageView does not call release on its data.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `[imageView removeFromSuperview]`, it won't release anything.  You need to so `[imageView release]` afterward.  Even so, you still need to put your memory releasing for that view in `imageView`'s dealloc.

Comment: I thought [parentView addSubview: childView] retains childView and [parent removeFromSuperview: childView] releases childView. Both assumptions are wrong?

Comment: You might be right.  The way I mentioned is how I always thought it was.  Lets see if someone else says I'm wrong. :)